# Android: permissions missing name and tags

Tags: eclipse, android-manifest, android-permissions

I am quite new to Android programming and am attempting to create an app, but I wanted to make sure that I have everything correct and error free before I do. I have the following errors in my manifest file: missing name attribute in element ....and tag permission missing required attribute name. I thought I did have a name in permission ("@string/app_name") but the error is still there! here is a copy of the code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="s.p.cunningham.checkyournumberslotteryapp"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
<permission android:name="@string/app_name"></permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="s.p.cunningham.checkyournumberslotteryapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Ok thanks but I did that because stack overflow wouldnt let me post the question otherwise. That actually doesnt help in answering my question? Does anyone know the answer to my question?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the whole  tag. It is not a requirement in most of the cases, but god know's why comes as default when you create a new android application project.

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't required, you can delete that tag... if you want to add any permission, then , delete that and use

```
<uses-permission
android:name="your permission....."
/>
```